# Hash calculation using T-SQL update statement to generate 32 bit length

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

How can I change this code to make it work in SQL Server? This doesn't work in SQL Server right now.

The statement works to calculate checksum in Oracle. How can I adapt it for SQL Server?

```
    UPDATE Work 
  set ETL_CHECKSUM =  HASHBYTES('MD5',concat(
    Branch, '|',
    Group, '|', 
    Number, '|', 
    Column, '|',
    dDate, '|', 
   Basis, '|',
    per, '|',
     Mult, '|', 
     nDate, '|', 
     Key, '|', 
    INSERT_TS))
```

Comment: How to make *what* work in SQL Server? This isn't SQL. I assume some database allows calls like `dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5(input => UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(...))`. It would be better to explain what you want to do though - `I want to hash a row's values`

Comment: In SQL Server you can use the [HASHBYTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to cryptographically hash a value. As the documentation explains, in the latest versions only SHA2 is supported as earlier hash algorithms are unsafe. Older algorithms will still work but issue warnings

Comment: Shore, MD5 is outdated and insecure. But it produces no warnings at all. Where do you get warnings?

Comment: @Sebastian it's in the docs `Beginning with SQL Server 2016 (13.x), all algorithms other than SHA2_256, and SHA2_512 are deprecated. Older algorithms (not recommended) will continue working, but they will raise a deprecation event.`

Comment: @user10260750 what are you trying to do? A hash that includes *itself* in the calculation can't be validated, it's almost *guaranteed* to be different from its original value. Next time you try to calculate it, it will be different. This means it's useless

Comment: I tried it right now with SQL2017 and there was no warning raised. That's why I am wondering.

Comment: As a general rule, you should not be hashing with MD5 due to known collisions. You should consider using SHA2.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a function named **HASHBYTES** for this:

```
DECLARE @hashThis nvarchar(max);
SET @hashThis = CONCAT(Branch, Discou, ...);  
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', @hashThis);
```

Have a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Also keep in mind that not all functionality is available in all SQL Server versions. HASHBYTES is available since SQL Server 2008. CONCAT is available since SQL Server 2012. When using SQL Server 2017, you might also use CONCAT_WS.

Comment: I assume that the system used, is contemporary. If somebody needs info about stone age, he has to state it. ;)

Comment: Yes, I agree when a specific version is not specified by the OP, like in this case. Nevertheless it often remains important, since many organizations often don't upgrade their server systems that much. And regarding the fact that the OP posts data in his question that does not indicate a thorough experience with the SQL Server platform, mentioning this version support per function did not seem unnecessary to me. ;)

Comment: You are mixing the two ways of concatenating. In the function CONCAT() you don't need the '|'.

Comment: I tried SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5',concat( 'Branch', 'DiscountGroup', 'ItemNumber', 'PriceColumn', 'LastUpdatedDate', 'PMBasis', 'PMOper', 'PMMult', 'DeletedOnDate', 'PriceMatrixKey', 'ODS_INSERT_TS')) on my SQL2017 which resulted in '0x9B82DD8D902F16D86DF7BC1EEDA16E5B' . Whats happening when you execute this exampe with hard coded strings?

Comment: when i change it back to update string it generates šlÆ¦Ç³=ZÒ›Øa as checksum value

Comment: The return value is of the *varbinary* type. This happens when you just cast it to varchar. For display, you must convert it. SELECT CONCAT('0x', CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HASHBYTES('MD5',concat( 'Branch', 'DiscountGroup', 'ItemNumber', 'PriceColumn', 'LastUpdatedDate', 'PMBasis', 'PMOper', 'PMMult', 'DeletedOnDate', 'PriceMatrixKey', 'ODS_INSERT_TS')), 2))

Comment: Depends on where you want to insert. My sample is suitable to insert into a varchar column.

Comment: My oracle function length generates 32 bit length and this generates 16 bit lengh how can i match it?

Comment: UPDATE ETL_SSIS.PriceMatrix_Work
SET SET ETL_CHECKSUM = CONCAT('0x', CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HASHBYTES(MD5,concat( Branch, DiscountGroup, ItemNumber, PriceColumn, LastUpdatedDate, PMBasis, PMOper, PMMult, DeletedOnDate, PriceMatrixKey, ODS_INSERT_TS)), 2))

Comment: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You maybe have to adapt this example a bit. I don't know your data structure. The hardcoded example is working. Take this and transfer it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server introduced a [HASHBYTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function. This works on varchar, nvarchar and varbinary data.

```
DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(4000);  
SET @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),'dslfdkjLK85kldhnv$n000#knf');  
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', @HashThis);
```

See other hashing algorythms available at the link.